# Enabling/disabling input into certain fields based on the value of another field

Tags: ms-access, expression, ms-access-2010

In the data entry form frmlastweeksactivities . When a row has "Gold"or "Silver" or "Bronze" as content in the [“category of activity “] field /column then disable  columns/fields[5] & [6]

When a row has "Wood" or "Hay"or "Stubble "as content in the [“category of activity “] field /column then disable columns/fields[8] & [9]

Disable means not allow any data entry in this case turn them red as well would be nice

I am trying to build and expression to use in either the table validation rule properties or in one of the control -txt boxes in the form

Comment: You'd do best to use validation in the form rather than the table as the form is where you want to disable controls (where data is entered) based on the logic you define.  Are you talking about  adding new records or updating existing records?  The `AfterUpdate` event is fired for a control when the user changes its value, and in the VBA code behind this event you can define your custom actions (e.g. set the `Enabled` property for other controls on the form).

See this example http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=209730

Comment: Thanks  for this 
My plan is to use Table validation rules as at this stage as VBA  is somewhat above my current skill level.So I  am just looking for an expression  to put in the validation rule  box in the table properties  . I am only interested in future records entered  not in the existing records .my hope is that the few operators that use the  database will quickly learn what data the  need to put in where  so form validation is a nice thought but perhaps over kill for what I need to get done at present  .thanks again

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible to do what you want in the table validation rule.  I checked for myself and Access threw an exception: `Invalid SQL syntax - cannot use multiple columns in a column-level CHECK constraint`.  It would also be much better practice to improve the user experience by restricting them from using the controls in the first place.  I'll post a VBA example below and you should find it easy enough to implement.

Comment: I was wrong above.  It is possible to create a table-level validation rule but it is not as good a solution as the disabling of controls in the form.  I've updated my solution to reflect this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: Solution using table-level validation**

The table-level solution will not disable fields, all it will do is validate a record as it is added.  If the validation rule fails (evaluates to `FALSE`) then the user will be presented with a warning message and the update will be cancelled (record not added).

The expression for this should be entered in the `Validation Rule` Table Property as follows:

```
IIf((([category]="gold" Or [category]="silver" Or [category]="bronze") And (Len([Field5])>0 Or Len([Field6])>0)) 
 Or (([category]="Wood" Or [category]="stubble" Or [category]="hay") And (Len([Field8])>0 Or Len([Field9])>0))
,False,True)
```

*WARNING: MAKE SURE THE BRACKETS LINE UP AS PER THE EXPRESSION ABOVE!!*

The expression is messy but it tests whether either of 2 "fail conditions" you describe are true, namely:

1) Category = gold/silver/bronze AND not null value in Field5/Field6

2) Category = wood/stubble/hay AND not null value in Field8/Field9

Then in the `Validation Text` property of the Table Property Sheet enter the text you wish to notify the user that their record fails and needs correction before the record can be saved.  For example:

```
"If category is gold/silver/bronze then Field5 and Field6 must be blank, if wood/stubble/hay then Field8 and Field9 blank.  Record not saved, please correct before saving."
```

Here is a screen shot of the table in design view showing the Property Sheet and the 2 properties you need to change.

[image]

---

**BETTER: Solution using event-driven validation & control locking within the Form**

Given that Access table-level and field-level validation will not do what is required, this solution will utilise event-driven validation on the form.  It assumes that you have a form with text box controls called `category`, `Field5`, `Field6`, `Field8` and `Field9`.

With the form in design view, right click on the `category` field (or press `ALT` and `ENTER` simultaneously) to view the properties for the control.  In the Property Sheet on the right of the screen click on the `Events` tab.  This displays the possible events for the selected control.  See the screenshot below.

[image]

You are interested in the `After Update` event so click in it and then the buttton to the right `...`.  Choosing `Code Builder` will open up a new VBA module for the form and create an event automatically for you.

```
Private Sub category_AfterUpdate()

    ' by default enable all four fields 5/6/8/9
    Me.Field5.Enabled = True
    Me.Field6.Enabled = True
    Me.Field8.Enabled = True
    Me.Field9.Enabled = True

    ' test the value entered by user in the category field and hide fields as required
    Select Case Me.category
        Case "Gold", "Silver", "Bronze"
            ' if the user has entered Gold, Silver or Bronze lock Fields 5/6
            Me.Field5.Enabled = False
            Me.Field6.Enabled = False
        Case "Wood", "Stubble", "Hay"
            ' if the user has entered Gold, Silver or Bronze lock Fields 8/9
            Me.Field8.Enabled = False
            Me.Field9.Enabled = False
    End Select

End Sub
```

So the code above will ensure that when the user updates the `category` field the code between `Sub` and `End Sub` will run and this code sets the `Enabled` property for the fields you mentioned as per your logic.  This `Enabled` property if set to `False` will lock the field from becoming active (accepting the cursor) and will grey it out so users are aware it is disabled.

Finally, when the user moves onto a new record you need to add one more piece of code, to reset the 4 fields to being `Enabled`.  So back in the form in design view, access the properties for the `Form` object itself either by clicking on a part of the form but NOT on a control.  For example click in the form header or footer.  When you see the event properties for the form you will see an event named `Current`.  This is the one you need to create an event procedure for in much the same way as above with the `...` button.  This will take you into the VBA window again and you need to make sure that the following code is entered there:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    ' by default enable all four fields 5/6/8/9
    Me.Field5.Enabled = True
    Me.Field6.Enabled = True
    Me.Field8.Enabled = True
    Me.Field9.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

This is a screenshot of how the VBA screen should look with all of your code in it.

[image]

When you now save and run your form it should behave exactly as you wish.  Any questions or issues please comment and I'll try to assist.

Comment: This reply is far clearer than I have ever  ever received before on any Access Forum I have ever visited will report  how successful I have been at applying it  in next 24 hrs Thanks

Comment: HI  I have  implemented this solution and it works well. There is a problem though which is :-

Comment: HI  I have  implemented this  solution 2 as described and it works well. There is a problem though which is :-  The fields are disabled as required during new records BUT if for some reason a user goes back over  the records they have already entered ,say to check them they can then enter data in the wrong field .  I am going to experiemnt  and see what happens if i leave out the second part of the vba module that controls the  current property

Comment: yes it  works  fine now   any guidance as to problems this approach might yield  of not resetting the form   would be welcome

Comment: one slight observation for those reading this-- Access prompted me to in form properties  to select "YEs " for the HAsModule  form property I ignored this  to begin with --  and of course the module did Nowwat  nothing zilch . put once I had selected YEs and saved it  it worked swimmingly .. very well  SO MAtt Thanks for your help

Comment: Tto Resume  I adopted the solution " BETTER: Solution using event-driven validation & control locking within the Form"   I did not event try the table validation solution as i accepted that his was a non started for my needs

Comment: Huston we have a problem ..  my form seems disconnected from the table  i can happily enter data via the form  but there is no data getting  into the  table  Have I turned something off

Comment: I couldn't explain what has occurred with your form and it's link to the table.  You make a good point, silly me: in the `Form_Current` event we need some code to check whether it is a new record or an existing record.  `if Me.NewRecord then`... I will update the solution in the morning.
Normally the Form Module would be created from the form, by clicking on the View Code toolbar button (top right) or by adding the first event.
Glad the solution is satisfactory and I hope this shows you that VBA codiing is not as painful as you imagined.

Comment: As an aside, it is a good idea to split your application into a Front End/Back End architecture so you can easily make changes and test the Front End against a copy of the back end before going live.  Here is one article about that, there are other (better?) articles out there which explain why to do it.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304932