# Enabling/disabling input into certain record's field based on the value of another field, but at the same record

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I work with Access 2016 and I'm trying to lock/unlock the fields (Epileptic_activity, Quantifiable_activity and Seizure_aspect) in each record, when "Selection"=No/Yes respectively (I have Yes/No in selection). All that is happening in the subform of big navigation form.

I used this method
[Enabling/disabling input into certain fields based on the value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923650/enabling-disabling-input-into-certain-fields-based-on-the-value-of-another-field)
and it work, but it locks/unlocks all the data displayed in the form. 
As soon as I check any Selection to Yes, all the records have Epileptic_activity, Quantifiable_activity and Seizure_aspect unlocked.

Here is the code which I used:

```
Private Sub Selection_AfterUpdate()

Me.Epileptic_activity.Enabled = True

Me.Quantifiable_activity.Enabled = True

Me.Seizure_aspect.Enabled = True

If (Me.Selection = False) Then

    Me.Epileptic_activity.Enabled = False

    Me.Quantifiable_activity.Enabled = False

    Me.Seizure_aspect.Enabled = False

    End If

End Sub
```

So, I would like to be able to lock/unlock the fields following Selection recordwise, because in one record we could have Selection and the following fields are necessary, but the next record doesn't have Selection="yes" and then I would expect to have 3 following fields locked.

How can I make it work?

thx for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change that, this is how Access works.

However, you can enable/disable each control individually every time the control gets the focus by checking the `Selection` value.

```
Private Sub Epileptic_activity_Enter()

    If Selection.Value = False Then Epileptic_activity.Enabled = False Else Epileptic_activity.Enabled = True

    'or simply

    Epileptic_activity.Enabled = Selection.Value

End Sub
```

You will need to do this for all three controls.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Pity, I can't disable row by row, but OK, can be like this